# Folders, shares and permissions

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, nfs

I want to organise my home network for my family, so:

- kids get their own login (probably on a Windows machine).
- Kids get read/write access to their own folder.
- Kids get read-only access to a folder with, for example, movies.
- I have read/write access to the kids' folders.
- I have my own folders, which the kids can't access with their login.
- I
  share a folder with my girlfriend (who has her own login), which the
  kids can't access.
- And so on :)

In the above, where I say 'folder', I mean a network share (Samba for Windows, preferably NFS for Macs - it's faster, right?).

I have a local server running Ubuntu Server 14.04.1. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: See https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html and http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-set-permissions-to-samba-shares.html